# Edges' length in diagraph on Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I need to create a digraph on Matlab. I have the sources, the targets and the matrix with the weights. Normally, all that is needed is the line:

```
G = digraph(S,T,weights);
```

My problem is that although I don't have the coordinates of nodes, I do have the lengths of the edges linking the nodes.
In order to have the weights being represented as edges' width, I have this:

```
LWidths = (1/max(G.Edges.Weight))*G.Edges.Weight;
p.LineWidth = LWidths;
```

How can I take into account also the length and have it imported from the user, and not by default?

Comment: If you change `weights` to be the *lengths* of the edges, you can use `layout` with the [`'WeightEffect'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot.layout.html?s_tid=doc_ta#mw_3b90f3f2-7b4f-4263-bbb3-1e4a496b9181) option to make the edge lengths proportional to its weight. You can still use your previous vector of weights to specify the line widths.

Comment: @beaker thanks
According to your instructions and some documentation, I have this:
 see update, above

Comment: If that's working for you, then you can post that as an answer, preferably with a sample plot image.

Answer (score 1):

After defining sources, targets, weights and lengths:

```
G = digraph(S,T,lengths);
p = plot(G);
G.Edges.Weight = lengths';
layout(p,'force','WeightEffect','direct')
G.Edges.LWidths = 7*weights'/max(weights);
p.LineWidth = G.Edges.LWidths;
```

[image: network]

, the edges lengths are dependent on the actual length thereof, and their width is proportional to their weights